# Magento 2: Fill dropdown with first level of category

Tags: magento2, category, drop-downs

I am creating a dropdown using phtml .. Is there any class, method or factory is exists through which I can get `toOptionarray()` of first level of category.

Answer (score 1):

Hello `@Rizwan` replace below code to your `toOptionArray()`

```
public function _getCategoryCollection($level)
{
$collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addIsActiveFilter()->addLevelFilter($level);  
return $collection;
}

public function toOptionArray(){
$arr = $this->_getCategoryCollection(1);
$category = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    $category[] = [
    'value' => $key,
    'label' => $value
    ];
  }
return $category;
}
```

Hope this will work.